# Proper workaround - there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mysql-error-1293

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data text,
  date_published timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  date_edited timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Giving me this error:

```
#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause.
```

There are older posts regarding this problem, but i want a proper workaround, due to current database structure.

Version: libmysql - 5.5.41
Running on: 5.5.41-ubuntu.14.04.1

Comment: "i want a proper workaround, due to current database structure" what do you mean by this? You don't mention a mysql version, or what the other answers were, that made them inappropriate

Comment: added db version now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a hard limitation. Best bet is making `date_edited` use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and managing `date_published` in your application.

```
date_published timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
date_edited timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Triggers might be an alternative option, but I try not to rely on stuff like that that can't easily be version-controlled.

Comment: @sdfgg45 That's a syntax error. I don't typically write out the SQL personally - you should be able to fix. The general idea is clear.

Comment: I only added your settings, and the result is also clear, it dossent work

Comment: @sdfgg45 As I said, 1064 is a syntax error. I likely didn't get the exact syntax for the database schema right. Fundamentally, the answer to your question is that you can't have two `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` columns in one table. Your application will need to manage one of them.

Comment: One of the dates looks like:0000000000 its not actually what i wanted.

Comment: Again, "what I wanted" and "what is possible" are different things here.